# QList<double> in QT with Visual Studio add in

Tags: c++

I am working on creating a simple List Widget that displays "double" values when a "run" button is clicked.  The widget contains 20 rows and 6 columns.  Right now, I would just like for the values to all be the same number. I have the widget displaying how I want it, however, I am new to C++ and am not sure how to get the values to display in the widget when I click a pushbutton "run".  Here is my code thus far:

```
qlistdouble.cpp


#include "qlistdouble.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QTableWidgetItem>

Qlistdouble::Qlistdouble(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

}

Qlistdouble::GetNumbers()
{

}


void Qlistdouble::MyClass(QList<double*> *slotString)
{
    connect(ui.getNumber, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(clear()));

    for( int row = 0; row < 20; row++ )
    {
        for( int column = 0; column < 6; column++ )

         {
            slotString = new QList<double*>;
            QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(5));
            ui.tableWidget_values->setItem(row, column, newItem);
        }
    }

}




qlistdouble.h


#ifndef QLISTDOUBLE_H
#define QLISTDOUBLE_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_qlistdouble.h"

class Qlistdouble : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Qlistdouble(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~Qlistdouble();
    void MyClass(QList<double*> *slotString);


private:
    Ui::QlistdoubleClass ui;
};

#endif // QLISTDOUBLE_H
```

I know that this is a simple question, but if someone could give me some suggestions on how to go about this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying lists in Qt is usually achieved through [QListView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistview.html) as a view and a [QAbstractListModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractlistmodel.html) as an underlying model. The list of [model view examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-itemviews.html) is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the source code of one of the simple example programs supplied with qt.  essentially all you need to do is construct a Qapplication and your main window class, then call show on the main window and then exec() to start the event loop.  I could write some from memory but the example code will be better.

Reading your comment, and using the very helpful link the other poster provided, I suggest starting with the trivial wizard example.  It is a complete executable in a single file.  You could put your own widget in one of the pages and calculate the numbers in when the page is shown.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-trivialwizard.html

If this still seems too complex, then I suggest you may be trying to do too much as initial step.  In this case I suggest instead writing a console application that prints the numbers to std::cout.

Comment: I've been looking at the examples, and they are a bit more complicated than what I am capable of doing.  Do you mind writing some from memory?  I basically want to create a class called "GetNumbers" and I want the class to  produce random numbers (or the same number) for each row and column (20 rows and 6 columns).. I hope I am using the correct lingo... 

    void Qlistdouble::GetNumbers()
    {
    }

I don't know what to put inside of those brackets to produce the numbers.